# Add style cell to DataTable from database

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I´m trying to add style to my cell according to status of call.

One call can have one of these statuses:

- new
- pending
- canceled
- confirm
- commercialiced

And this style it´s in table from DB in columns:

`span_class` and `class` with this content:

> span_class: badge bg-primary text-white
> class: badge bg-primary text-white

for example.

I want to add this styles to my column status in my datatable.

i think that i can to do this in `columns` with render, but i don´t know how i can to do this.

my columns is:

```
columns: [
  { data: '', name: '' },
  { data: 'identi', name: 'identi' },
  { data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre' },
  { data: 'direccion', name: 'direccion' },
  { data: 'provincia', name: 'provincia' },
  { data: 'ciudad', name: 'ciudad' },
  { data: 'teleoperadora', name: 'teleoperadora' },
  { data: 'reasignar', name:'reasignar', 'render': function ( data, type, row ) {
      return "<select class='select_operator'><option>-- Seleccione --</option></select>";
  },       
  },
  { data: 'estado', name: 'estado' },
  { data: 'estadoCita', name: 'estadoCita' },
  { data: 'fechaAsignacion', render: function (data, type, row) {
      return moment(new Date(data).toString()).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
  } 
  },
  { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false },
],
```

in "estado"(status) i need add class

**updated**

I´m trying this:

```js
{
  data: 'estado',
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    return '<span class="' + data.clase + '">' + data.estado + '</span>';
  }
},
```

**updated**

```js
{
  data: 'estado',
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    return '<span class="' + row.class_span + " " + row.clase + '">' + row.estado + '</span>';
  }
},
```

Comment: Here is one approach: You are already using `render` functions in your example code. You can use a `render` function to create a span for your `estado` cells: `return '<span class="' + YOUR_CLASS_NAME + '">' + data + '</span>';`. I assume there is a simple mapping from the `estado` value in each cell to the class name you want to use. You can include that logic in the render function.

Comment: If you need to get the class names from the database, instead of hard-coding them in the render function, then they have to be provided in the JSON data you pass to your DataTable - so that may also need to be changed in your code.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks for your response. I´m traying to do that you say me, but i don´t know to do... Return undefined. Updated my question

Comment: OK - thank you for the updates. The `data` variable in your render function only refers to the `estado` value - it does not refer to anything else. You need to use the  `row` variable to access the other fields in that record. For example, `row.clase`. But that assumes your JSON contains `clase` as a field. IF it's not in the JSON, this will not work. Can you show us the raw text of your JSON?

Comment: thanks for your help @andrewjames i resolve my problem with your help. I update my question with my actual code

Comment: Glad you solved it! You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), if you want to help other people. You can also accept your own answer.

Comment: Just to note, (1) you don't need to use `row.estado`. You can use `data` - because your column definition already defined `data` as follows: `data: 'estado'`. (2) You can add `console.log( data );` and `console.log( row );` to your render function (for debugging purposes) to see what those variables contain. I think you would have solved your problem for yourself, if you had done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this resolve my problem. I have one `JSON` in my query in controller and return  value css that i need. after i put class into my td with:

```
{ data: 'estado', render: function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="'+row.class_span+" "+row.clase +'">' + row.estado + '</span>';
                } 
            },
```